# Write parquet to S3 using Spark Scala: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

When I tried to write parquet to s3 with Scala using the code below:

```
ab.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(path)
```

And the error shows:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted. (Job aborted.) ......
>   rg.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task
>   1 in stage 112.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in
>   stage 112.0 (TID 6273, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AOutputStream.(S3AOutputStream.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:410)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)

Comment: is your path right? Can you show it to us?

Comment: My path is right, and it's like "s3a://.../"

Comment: And the bucket? Does it already exist?

Comment: I've tried to use a existing bucket and a non-exist bucket, which both of them didn't work.

Comment: @ZoeCheung Do you have aws-java-sdk version 1.7.4 in you project?

Comment: I don't have a aws-java-sdk in my project...